# Issue with SequelizeJS and models

Tags: sequelize.js

I get an issue declaring models with SequelizeJS. When I need to use associations I get a type error...

Error : `TypeError: ArticleCategoryModel is not a function`

**ArticleModel.js**

```
var Sequelize             = require('sequelize'),
    ArticleCategoryModel  = require('./ArticleCategoryModel');

module.exports = function(sequelize) {

  var Article = sequelize.define('article', {
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    content: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  });

  Article.belongsTo(ArticleCategoryModel(sequelize));

  Article.sync(/*{force: true}*/);

  return Article;
};
```

**ArticleCategoryModel.js**

```
var Sequelize             = require('sequelize'),
    ArticleModel          = require('./ArticleModel');

module.exports = function(sequelize) {

  var ArticleCategory = sequelize.define('article_category', {
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  });

  ArticleCategory.hasMany(ArticleModel(sequelize), { foreignKey: 'categoryId' });

  ArticleCategory.sync(/*{force: true}*/);

  return ArticleCategory;
};
```

**ArticleCategoryController.js**

```
var sequelize = require('../../databases/Database').connexion,
var ArticleCategoryModel = require('./ArticleCategoryModel')(sequelize);
```

**The full stack error (with external files) :**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\****\app\models\ArticleModel.js:29
  Article.belongsTo(ArticleCategoryModel(ArticleCategoryModel));
                    ^

TypeError: ArticleCategoryModel is not a function
    at module.exports (C:\xampp\htdocs\****\app\models\ArticleModel.js:29:21)
    at module.exports (C:\xampp\htdocs\****\app\models\ArticleCategoryModel.js:14:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\****\app\controllers\ArticleCategoryController.js:3:72)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\****\server.js:55:18
    at arrayEach (C:\xampp\htdocs\****\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:508:11)
    at Function.forEach (C:\xampp\htdocs\****\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9334:14)
    at init (C:\xampp\htdocs\****\server.js:53:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\****\index.js:3:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

**Something you need to know :**

When I remove these lines, everything works.

```
ArticleCategory.hasMany(ArticleModel(sequelize), { foreignKey: 'categoryId' });
Article.belongsTo(ArticleCategoryModel(sequelize));
```

Comment: why require('ArticleCategoryModel') and not require('./ArticleCategoryModel'). Also is there a circular dependency

Comment: With `./` I get the same error. I've edited the code.

Comment: Can you give the entire error stack?

Comment: See edit with the entire error and notice about associations...